# I want to find which publisher had the highest global sales between the specific dates. Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

[image: Table Column Layout]

So far i've got:

```
SELECT Publisher, MAX(Global_Sales) AS Most_Sales
FROM Vgsales
WHERE Year BETWEEN 1980 AND 1990;
```

but not sure whether this is correct or not.

Comment: *but not sure whether this is correct or not* so if *you* don't know if your output is correct, how does anyone else?

Comment: 'Am I doing this correctly' - No. It would be very simple to mock up some data and test it. Also please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html and consider using an order by with limit.

Answer (score 0):

Among the countless ways, you can use something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SUM(global_sales) total, publisher FROM VGSALES
  WHERE year BETWEEN 1999 AND 2000
  GROUP BY publisher
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE total = (SELECT MAX(total) FROM cte)
```